# Could not access method of backend in api module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a yii2 advanced template project and has 4 main modules.`backend`,`frontend`,`api` and `common`.

I have recently created a component in `common` which has 2 3 function in it.Main method is `sendMessage` which uses another method in same class which is `findModel($id)`.

When i access this component from `backend` i can access that component with following line

```
Yii::$app->myComponent->sendMessage()
```

but i cant use the same code in `api` module.

Is there a specific reason for that or is there another way to access all those component methods in `api` module from common component.

I have created a restful api in that `api` folder.

Comment: have you defined your components in `common/config/main.php` or `backend/config/main.php`? And does your api-config merge with common-config?

Comment: @Jørgen I have defined in `common/config/main.php` but i dont know how to merge `api-config` with `common-config`. I have added `api` in `common/config/aliases.php`. Can you give me an example of how to merge? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would have to merge your config file with the components settings into your api config. In the [request lifecycle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-workflow.html#request-lifecycle) you can see that the configurations are set before the application is initiated. So in your case your `api/web/index.php` would look something like your `backend/web/index.php`:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
   require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
   require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
   require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
   require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Remember that this is environmentally different depending on weather you're in `dev` or `prod`.

Comment: yes i do have that same file in all folders `backend/web`,`frontend/web` and `api/web`